# Event in canvas (In Android compilation) only have the key isTrusted (Ionic 6)

Tags: typescript, events, dom-events, ionic-native, ionic5

I have a problem, I intend to simulate a mousepad in my ionic project, but we run into the problem that when I compile the program with the command:

```
ionic cordova run android --device -l -c -s --debug --consolelogs --host 192.168.0.16
```

I have the problem that when I do it with the ionic it serves we work properly returning a complete event object to me, but when I compile the application to test it on android the event only has the key `isTrusted: true`

Can anyone help us?

I attach my code:

page.html

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Tab 1
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <ion-header collapse="condense">
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title size="large">Tab 1</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <div id="container">
    <ion-button (click)="clickButton()" expand="block">Click</ion-button>
    <canvas #canvas no-bounce id="mousepad" (touchmove)="handleMove($event);" height="{{this.screenSize.height}}" width="{{this.screenSize.width}}" style="margin:0 auto; background-color: black;"></canvas>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

page.ts

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ComputerService } from '../services/computer.service';
import { Platform, ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page implements OnInit {
  private screenSize = null;
  private screen_relation = 6;
  public click_event = "";
  constructor(private computer: ComputerService, public toastController: ToastController, private platform: Platform) {}

  public handleMove(event){
    console.log(event);
  }

  public async clickButton(e){
    console.log(e)
    try{
      let result = await this.computer.getScreenSize();
      let toast = null;
      if(result != null){
        toast = await this.toastController.create({
          message: JSON.stringify(result.data),
          duration: 5000
        });
      }
      toast.present();
    } catch(err) {
      let toast = await this.toastController.create({
        message: JSON.stringify(err),
        duration: 5000
      });
      toast.present();
    }
  }

  public getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: (evt.clientX - rect.left) / (rect.right - rect.left) * canvas.width,
        y: (evt.clientY - rect.top) / (rect.bottom - rect.top) * canvas.height
    };
  }
  async ngOnInit() {
    let result = await this.computer.getScreenSize();
    if(result != null){
      this.screenSize = result;
      this.screenSize.width = this.screenSize.width / this.screen_relation;
      this.screenSize.height = this.screenSize.height / this.screen_relation;
      let canvas = document.getElementById('mousepad');
      canvas.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        let x = this.getMousePos(canvas, e);
        this.moveMouse(x);
      });
    } else {
      console.log("is null");
    }
  }

  public async moveMouse(mousePos:any) {
    let coord = {
      x: mousePos.x * this.screen_relation,
      y: mousePos.y * this.screen_relation
    }
    let result = await this.computer.moveToPos(coord);
  }
}
```

PS: It should be noted that we have happened with all events. in ionic serve it works fine for me, but when I compile it on Android it doesn't.